# ggplot2: Plot discrete factors with a set of similar colours

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to come up with a consistent way of representing each factor in my dataset when plotting them. So, for example, I could have the levels of "Part of Speech" represented by different shades of blue every time I'm graphing something involving part of speech:

```
eg.dat <- data.frame(rt=c(530, 540, 555), 
                     part.of.speech=c("Verb", "Noun", "Both")
                     )

ggplot(eg.dat, aes(part.of.speech, rt, fill=part.of.speech)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("cyan", "blue", "darkblue"))
```

[image: Specifying colours manually]

Coming up with fancy colour names like this for every factor is difficult, however, so I've been looking for more automatic solutions. One fairly hackish workaround is to use `alpha`:

```
ggplot(eg.dat, aes(part.of.speech, rt, alpha=part.of.speech)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", fill="blue") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.4, 1))
```

[image: Using alpha]

But I've been wondering whether there's any easier way to select a short range of similar colours like this. The `scale_colour_gradient` type functions in `ggplot2` don't work with discrete factors like these, and it doesn't seem particularly easy to get custom colours out of `rainbow` or `heat.colors`. The ideal function would be something like: 
`shades(n, central_colour="blue")`, returning `n` colour values. Any suggestions for the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `?scale_fill_brewer` uses `R` package `RColorBrewer` which implements the ideas shown on website [http://colorbrewer2.org/](http://colorbrewer2.org/).

Comment: Even better `?scale_fill_hue`

Comment: As a side note (I know, I'm being 'That Guy'), it's generally not recommended to use colour like this (the parts of speech are already separated by the different columns) as it distracts from the values. Take a look at the bar graphs on pages 2 and 3 of this pdf: http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/rules_for_using_color.pdf

Comment: @sebastian-c It's completely redundant here, but when I get to the point where I'm graphing e.g. separate regression lines for each part of speech, I feel it helps both me and the reader to have established a representation scheme for that factor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`scale_fill_discrete` or `scale_fill_hue` will do this. You can define `h`, `c` and `l` (hue, chroma and luminance). See `?hcl` for more detail

eg.

```
ggplot(eg.dat, aes(part.of.speech, rt, fill=part.of.speech)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black") +
     scale_fill_discrete( h =c(220,260))
```

[image]

`scale_fill_hue` will give the same results (in this case).

You could also use `scale_fill_brewer` which uses the `RColorBrewer` package and gives access to the [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) palettes

```
ggplot(eg.dat, aes(part.of.speech, rt, fill=part.of.speech)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black") +
     scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Blues')
```

[image]

Comment: We're probably getting too far into subjective territory here, but to me the hues you get out of `scale_fill_hue` don't seem as good as `scale_fill_alpha`- either they're too similar, or it becomes less obvious that they're shades of the same colour. One of the side effects of `alpha` is probably that the chroma and luminance are changing, it's a pity you can't do the same with `scale_fill_hue`.

Comment: You would have to play around with h, c and l to get a 'good' range. The `brewer` approach is simpler as the palettes are predefined and the result of scientific research to get the optimal colours.

Comment: @Marius, The Color Brewer `sequential` palettes are optimized to be sequential and well separated. You can easily experiment with all 19 possibilities by changing the palette number: `scale_fill_brewer(type="seq", palette=1)`